# Selecting fields from two relational tables and formatting results in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have  question about selecting two table and showing results in format. Suppose that tables are;

table_1;

```
+-----+-----------+
| Ref | MaterialX |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 | mmm       |
|   1 | nnn       |
|   1 | kkk       |
+-----+-----------+
```

table_2;

```
+-----+-----------+
| Ref | MaterialY |
+-----+-----------+
|   1 | aaa       |
|   1 | bbb       |
+-----+-----------+
```

Pseudo query is; select two table and merge results acoording to ref field (ref and material fields are not primary key, Thoose are only relational thirth table)

Result (I wanted);

```
+-----+-----------+-----------+
| Ref | MaterialX | MaterialY |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
|   1 | mmm       | NULL      |
|   1 | nnn       | NULL      |
|   1 | kkk       | NULL      |
|   1 | NULL      | aaa       |
|   1 | NULL      | bbb       |
+-----+-----------+-----------+
```

Is there any way?

Comment: You can use simple union all since both tables are unrelated. `SELECT ref, materialX, null as MaterialY from table_1 union all SELECT ref, null as materialX, MaterialY from table_2`

Comment: @Koushik Roy it would be valid to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple union all since both tables are unrelated.

```
SELECT ref, materialX, null as MaterialY from table_1 
union all 
SELECT ref, null as materialX, MaterialY from table_2
```

Comment: That's incorrect, a UNION is for connecting two queries with the rows of the second appended to the rows of the first. See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html Not what the OP is describing.

Comment: Te result of query looks exact as OP's desired result: https://sqlize.online/?phpses=null&sqlses=7c672455fce0c230ba341e4062a63319&php_version=null&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: You might want to add an `ORDER BY` clause to ensure that all values with the same `ref` are sorted together.